# Terraform: Cloud Storage failed: storage: bucket doesn't exist

Tags: cloud, terraform

Friends,

I am trying to configure terraform to store its state in a bucket of gcloud but I am getting this error:

```
Error inspecting states in the "gcs" backend: querying Cloud Storage failed: 
storage: bucket doesn't exist.
```

I created the bucket previously using terraform and after that I am trying to run `terraform init` which returns the mentioned error. Here is the part of the code which may be relevant:

```
resource "google_storage_bucket" "state_bucket"{
  name                = var.bucket_name 
  location            = var.region
  force_destroy       = true 
}
```

How I created the bucket.

```
terraform {
    backend "gcs" {
        bucket      = "testing-state-7681715e9f673069edb4702f3986914e"
        prefix      = "terraform/state"
    }
}
```

And the backend.

Any idea what I may be missing? I am sure I am passing the correct bucket name. `terraform init -reconfigure` didn't work. I even tried destroying all the resources, deleting all the terraform files and redeploying them all over again but didn't work as well.

Comment: Did you end up resolving this?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I am facing the same issue but for me deleting the `.terraform` folder worked. Do `terraform init` after deleting the `.terraform` folder.